# How to translate "have a crush on somebody"?

Tags: traducción, selección-de-palabras

Which would be the translation to Spanish of

> I have a crush on your sister.

When speaking Spanish, everybody uses the English word and I'd like to know the translation.

Comment: What do you mean by "when speaking Spanish, everybody uses the English word"?

Comment: @JoulSauron I mean that they say "Tengo un *crush* con tu hermana."

Comment: Not Spain, what we use here might be the answers you are looking for ;)

Comment: I've never heard the word "crush" used here (Argentina).

Comment: I've never heard the word "crush" used in a spanish context. It's common in people that have lived for several months/years in an English speaking country. You can't generalize for everybody.

Comment: Where did you hear *crush* adopted into Spanish?  Just curious.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The use of the word `crush` in spanish sounds more like `spanglish` to me, at least I've never heard of people using it that way...

JoulSauron is right to mention the colloquialism of those expressions, as neither of those are used in Mexico (they *may* be understood in the right context, but I've never heard them being used here). However I'd use:

- Estoy loco por tu hermana (or tu hermana me trae loco)
- Estoy enamorado de tu hermana
- Estoy interesado (romanticamente) en tu hermana
- Me gusta (mucho) tu hermana
- Me atrae tu hermana

Which may or may not be used in other places as well...

Comment: I wouldn't use "enamorado" for "crush" in Spain, as it has the meaning of being in love, which is different from a crush. The same goes for the rest of sentences, they have their own translation to English and each of them give a different touch to the meaning of liking someone.

Comment: @JoulSauron I get your point and the same is also true in Mexico, however `enamorado` for example while having the main meaning just as the one you mention, can also be used for crush

Comment: I disagree with JoulSauron  and  I think that the closest global translation would be _Estoy loco por tu hermana_ or _tu hermana me trae loco_. But to get the most appropriate translation for that one have to choose a country, in this case. In some regions in Colombia (not in all) we use _Estoy tragado de tu hermana_ but we'll perfectly understand _Estoy loco por tu hermana_

Answer (score 10):

Some phrases we use in Spain for "crush":

- Estoy colado/coladito por tu hermana.
- Estoy colgado por tu hermana.
- Estoy pillado por tu hermana.

As these are colloquial, I'm guessing in other countries they use other expressions. Definitely, not everybody uses the English word, actually I would say just in few countries is used "crush" in Spanish.

Answer (score 4):

In Puerto Rico people would translate "crush" as ***enchule***.

Example:

> I have a crush on you

We would say

> Estoy enchulada de ti

Answer (score 4):

I am adding this summary following what was discussed in [Juntemos en respuestas wiki las respuestas cortas específicas de regiones / Let's use community wiki to summarize set of short region specific answers](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2483/5481). Feel free to edit to add the term used in your country or region.

---

### España

- Estar colado o pillado por alguien
  (Estoy **colado** por tu hermana; Estoy **pillado** de tu hermana)

### México

- Estar loco por, enamorado o interesado en alguien
  (Estoy **loco** por tu hermana; Estoy **enamorado** de tu hermana; Estoy **interesado** en tu hermana)

### Puerto Rico

- Enchule / Enchularse (Estoy **enchulado** de tu hermana)

### Perú

- Templarse de alguien (Estoy **templado** de tu hermana)

### Colombia

- (Tu hermana / alguien) me mueve el piso
- Me gusta tu hermana

Answer (score 2):

In Colombia, we say colloquially, "(tu hermana) me mueve el piso." As others have already observed, this expression varies from country to country. "Me gusta tu hermana" is likely the most universally-understood expression, but every culture tends to find creative ways to express emotion.

Comment: It might be better to add this into the community wiki answer about regional variation so they are all grouped together.

Comment: It works as an answer. It **could** also be added to the community wiki, but you could leave it here to help with your rep. Welcome MRogers.

Answer (score 1):

In some parts of Lima and provinces in Peru, I have heard people say:

> Carlos se me ha templado

or

> Me he templado de María